# Cannot get the list of available folders in a apache james mail server using JavaMail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, james

I am using javamail to access the available folders in james mail server but my code is throwing an exception

```
try {
            Store store = mailSession.getStore();
            store.connect("localhost", username , password );
            Folder folder = store.getDefaultFolder();
            Folder[] f = folder.list("*");

            for (Folder fd : f) {
                System.out.println(fd.getName());
            }

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Note : exception is thrown when calling list() method

Exception : **Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: A3 NO LIST failed. Search failed.**

Comment: Are there any folders defined on the server?

Comment: yes there are 4 folders Inbox , Outbox , Trash , and Drafts

Comment: The [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) might help debug the problem, but from the error message it sounds like a problem with the James server.